# What is name of process used to change sample bit depth?

Tags: dsp, sampling

Changing sampling rate is called up sampling or down sampling depending on which way or is done. If the factor is an even number then the process becomes very simple.

However, what term is used to change bit depth e.g 16 bit samples to 8 bit samples? Certainly this requires "re-quantization" rather than just throwing away least significant 8 bits.

Comment: I know different names for upsampling and downsampling and they are interpolation and decimation and they are not that simple, I also didn't understand your distinction of being even number or not. Usually they go together, for example, if you make decimation you can get more resolution (more bits)

Comment: Actually, the requantization is throwing away least significant bits.

Comment: Let's take an example, I have WAV file with each sample at 16 bits and I want to reduce it to 8 bits per sample. What is the process called? Re-quantization seems to be reasonable term. Basically the 16 bit signal shall be quantized to 8 resolution as if it was an analogue signal and the lower 8 bits shall not be thrown away.

Comment: I am confused, what % do the lower 8 bits represent of the total resolution in a 16 bit sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically it DOES amount to simply chopping off the lower bits and discarding them.

Now it may help to amplify (multiply) the signal up to some amplitude so that the signal will be above your new, higher zero threshold.

In some cases "dithering" is used to introduce low-level random ("noise") factors to make the sound more "natural". Although that is more common when the bit depth is increased (vs. decreasing it as you are asking about).

Comment: Huh. Dithering adds absolutely nothing when _increasing_ the bit depth. It's always done before _reducing_ the bit depth, as a way to mask the quantization noise, not only for audio but for other data as well.

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to "scaling". To go from 16 bits (arithmetic data, of course, not logical) to 8 is done by dividing by 256.

In some cases it's done by truncation, where the lsb's are simply discarded. If you want to be careful, you apply rounding to the lsb of the result, but then the result is the same as scaling.

Comment: For integers dividing by 256 is exactly equal to truncation plus rounding

Comment: And to add more bits there is a simple "trick" to preserve the magnitude relative to the new number of bits: Copy the original bits to your new unused bits. _00101100_ turns into _00101100 00101100_ after extending from 8 to 16 bits.

Comment: @slebetman - "but then the result is the same as scaling."

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the phrase "in some cases" is completely unnecessary (indeed, it is technically wrong since it is all cases in the case of regular digital audio).

Comment: @slebetman First of all, the question has nothing to do with audio. Second, even in audio you don't just chop off the LSB, since you may want to apply dithering first, or round the result in different ways depending on the data format (signed/unsigned etc)

Comment: @pipe, I think considering this to be relayed to audio is most reasonable. I don't think why audio be treated as a special case for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to reduce bit depth in the simplest possible way, dropping the least significant bits is indeed what you do, and that is called quantization or re-quantization. If you're asking about a more advanced method, then the term you're looking for might be "dithering", and unlike Richard Crowley said, at least in audio it is usually used when reducing bit depth. Indeed, it is used whenever it's not the total power of the quantization error that matters, but its spectrum.

"Noise-shaping" may also be a good search term if you want to know more.

Comment: Nope. Dithering is a separate stage that can _optionally_ be applied. It is perfectly valid and often preferred to reduce the bit depth without applying dithering, so calling the re-quantization "dithering" is incorrect.

Comment: You're technically right, but I believe dithering is the term the OP was looking for: "However, what term is used to change bit depth e.g 16 bit samples to 8 bit samples? Certainly this requires "re-quantization" rather than just throwing away least significant 8 bits."

Re-quantization would really be just throwing bits away.

Comment: @pipe I edited the answer to make the distinction clearer.